# Container and Footer

Tags: html, css

Why does this happen? The background color stops halfway down the page and the footer is in the entirely wrong place. I have gotten it down with a lot of margins otherwise it would sit where the background color ends. What to do?The height is set too 100% everywhere.

Link to webpage: http://minafiler.miun.se/~soka1401/TESTING/

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Just linking to live websites is not a good idea. See also [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it)

Answer (score 0):

Add `overflow` `hidden` on `.main` Class

```
.main {

    padding: 6% 6% 6% 6%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: hsla(172, 13%, 88%, 0.549);
    overflow: hidden;

}
```

Comment: Wow, that really helped, thanks! The background color is finally in place and the footer is way better. Just need to get it to not overlap the above container now! Thanks again! So easy yet costing so much problem!